# Euro 2012 questions

Tags: discussion

I notice that Euro 2012 questions are getting substantial views.

[This](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-are-those-blue-stripes-or-patches-on-balotelli-back) Euro 2012 question has 2,500+ views. [Another](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/958/why-did-greece-go-through-over-russia-in-euro-2012) Euro 2012 question has 10,000+ views.

The [question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1040/soccer-shot-vs-hockey-shot) asked before [What are those blue stripes or patches on Balotelli back?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/what-are-those-blue-stripes-or-patches-on-balotelli-back) only has ~25 views, and many other questions have very few views compared to Euro 2012 questions.

Granted, it's not ALL the Euro 2012 questions, but noticeable enough to ask this question: Is this a coincidence or is there a concrete reason for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the (mod-only) analytics data, it appears almost all of this traffic is coming organically from Google. Apparently a) people care *a lot* about the Euros, and b) Sports.SE ranks high enough to pick up a fair amount of the Euro traffic.

Hopefully some people like what they see enough to stay around and ask/answer football questions.

This also bodes well for the Olympics later this summer.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: How can you tell that the traffic came from google?

Comment: @DorCohen: The analytics data (again, not public) breaks it out. Roughly 90% of our traffic in the last month has been from search engines... and that's not including data from today, which hasn't been collected yet.

Comment: How can I be part of this site moderators?

Comment: @DorCohen community chooses the moderators on SE sites, so I presume once Sports Beta gets large enough there will be elections for new/more moderators